# Why does correcting the Optional Parameters cause an access violation?

Tags: c#, delphi

Talking to a Delphi DLL in c#.
The Delphi definition of the function is

```
function oziCreateWP(var Name: pchar; Symbol: integer; lat, lon: double; Altitude: double; 
  wpDate: double; MapDisplayFormat: integer; PointerDirection: integer;
  GarminDisplayFormat: integer; ForeColor, BackColor: integer;
  ProximityDistance: integer; var Description: pchar; FontSize: integer;
  FontStyle: integer; SymbolSize: integer): integer; stdcall;
```

The function creates a waypoint at the specified position with the specified parameters. The return value is the internal OziExplorer number of the Waypoint created. This number may need to be stored locally if the Waypoint is to be manipulated later in your program. For most parameters a value of -1 can be specified, this means use the OziExplorer default.
The ** indicates that the above option applies for the field.

`Name - the name of the waypoint
Symbol - the symbol number; **
lat,lon - the position in decimal degrees (WGS 84 datum)
Altitude - in meters (-777 = altitude unknown)
wpDate - the format of the date is at the end of this document; -1 = use todays date and time.
MapDisplayFormat - 0 to 8; **
PointerDirection - 0 to 3; **
GarminDisplayFormat - 0 to 2; **
ForeColor - RGB color; **
BackColor - RGB color; **
ProximityDistance - in meters (0 = no proximity)
Description - text string
FontSize - in points; **
FontStyle - 0 = normal; 1 = bold; **
SymbolSize - 17 = normal; **`

My C# definition is..

```
[DllImport("oziapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int oziCreateWP(ref string Name, int Symbol, double lat, double lon,
    double Altitude = oziAltitudeNull, double wpDate = oziDefault,
    int MapDisplayFormat = oziDefault, int PointerDirection = oziDefault,
    int GarminDisplayFormat = oziDefault, int ForeColor = oziDefault,
    int BackColor = oziDefault, int ProximityDistance = oziDefault, 
    ref string Description, int FontSize = oziDefault, 
    int FontStyle = oziDefault, int SymbolSize = oziDefault);
```

My implementation code is..

```
private void btnCreateAManualWP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int nTemp;
    int nAlt = -777;
    int nNegOne = -1;
    int nZero = 0;
    string cName = cWPName.Text;
    string cDescription = "No Description";
    nTemp = oziCreateWP(ref cName, nNegOne, Convert.ToDouble(cWPLat.Text), 
        Convert.ToDouble(cWPLon.Text), nAlt, nNegOne, nNegOne, nNegOne, nNegOne, nNegOne,
        nNegOne, nZero, ref cDescription, nNegOne, nNegOne, nNegOne);
    nTemp = oziRefreshMap();
}
```

With this I get a CS1737 `Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters` error message flagging description.
If I correct the parameters order in the definition and the call to fix this issue, I get a Memory Access violation error at run-time.

Comment: ow, can you please try to reformat the code?

Comment: @David Heffernan  I deleted the last question because the specific issue related to the question in regard to reading the DLL had been resolved, was and still is, working perfectly.  Again, I thank you for your assistance.  As previously indicated, I didn't create the C# definitions.  Just trying to use them.  I suspected I couldn't change the parameter order but the error message indicated it was required.  I shan't bother you anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure it has been resolved. How do you deallocate the strings returned by the DLL? SetLastError? Really? You might think you've solved it but given your manifest inexperience how can you be confident? I have experience of interop and I'm here to tell you that there are likely problems and that the code can seem to work and yet be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the parameters is part of the binary interface. The parameter order must be the same on both sides of the interface. If you change the order in the C# code, you'd need to change the Delphi code to match.

Presumably the Delphi code cannot be changed. So you will need to fix the C# code without changing parameter order. Do that by removing the setting of parameter defaults.

The `ref string` parameters are almost certainly wrong, although it's not possible to say with 100% certainty what they should be without more detail. The documentation for the library will presumably explain how the `var PChar` parameters are to be handled.

I'd be surprised if `SetLastError = true` was correct. Does this library really call `SetLastError`?

Comment: Ah Ha!  Removing all the defaults from the definition fixed it.  Thank you, thank you.  Yes, it really does call SetLastError.  The ref string parameters work fine.

Comment: I doubt that they do. The DLL really allocates using CoTaskMemAlloc? And it really calls SetLastError? Very unusual.

Comment: The function puts a waypoint on the map and attaches the Name and Description.  Both are appearing when/where they should.

Comment: It seems to work. But is it? You ignored my point about CoTaskMemAlloc. Why? I would have liked to have answered your last question properly but didn't get the chance. I can't force you to listen, but you should ask yourself if you know why I am talking about CoTaskMemAlloc? If you don't know why then are you sure you understand what you are doing?

Comment: I didn't ignore it, just didn't understand it.  And when the App did what I wanted/needed I didn't see the need to pursue.  I will freely admit I am learning this C# stuff and don't understand what I am doing totally.  Just applying the basics of my Delphi experience and trying to port it to C#.  I have since had a look at CoTaskMemAlloc and it is beyond me att.

Comment: I'm here to tell you that if you don't know why I'm talking about `CoTaskMemAlloc` then you cannot possibly be sure you are doing this right. Still, it seems like you aren't interested in whether or not your code is right, if it runs on your machine and appears to work, that's good enough for you, even if it might break somewhere else, or sometime else. I could have told you all about this at your last question if you had fixed it so I could answer.